# How to insert geopoint values in database?

Tags: android, geolocation

I have 2 Geopoint values and I want to save in local database but I dont know which datatype should I use to insert that values in local database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `long` as your datatype and store it in a SQLite database:

http://p-xr.com/android-tutorial-simple-but-persistent-data-storage/

The link contains info on making / adressing the SQLite db

Answer (score 1):

Best way, you have to get the longitude and latitude value from the GeoPoint as Long Value. Then you can store it in the Database.

```
long longitude=geopoint.getLongitudeE6();
long latitude=geopoint.getLatitudeE6();
```